# Ruby 1.9 blocks without variables

Tags: ruby, factory-bot, ruby-1.9

I'm upgrade a codebase from 1.8 to 1.9. I'm encountering a couple places in my code (only specs, not sure if that's a coincidence) where there are problems with blocks that don't have a variable. Giving them a dummy variable fixes the problem. Here's an example:

In a factory girl factory, this works under 1.8:

```
Factory.define :thing do |t|
  t.price { 1 - 0.01*rand(10) }
end
```

Under 1.9, `rand(10)` returns `nil`. Very odd. I was racking my brain for why the environment would be different inside the block. The thing is, `rand` isn't even from the standard library -- it's from the core language! So there isn't really a way that the environment would make a difference.

Then I remembered that some other places in my specs were breaking because of no-variable blocks, so on a whim I threw one in there, and lo and behold it worked.

```
Factory.define :thing do |t|
  t.price { |dummy| 1 - 0.01*rand(10) }
end
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Lambdas, Procs, & blocks all behave differently in Ruby, so please be certain to specify the correct one and not interchange them. I believe what you mean here is *blocks*, not Procs/lambdas.

Comment: whoops -- yeah I knew that, was just reading something else about lambdas and had it on the brain :D fixed now

Comment: this must have something to do with Factorygirl.  For example, this works just fine from my ruby version 1.9.2 irb: 5.times { puts rand(20) }

Comment: Here is a discussion about a topic like yours: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/229

May you try to call Kernel.rand() instead of rand() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recent versions of factory_girl, defining an attribute without a block argument uses instance_eval, and it assumes that bare method calls are looking for previous attribute definitions, methods on your model, or syntax methods like "create" or "build."

In order to make attributes like "open" or "file" work correctly, the proxy object undefines most private methods including "rand." This means that you need to use "Kernel.rand" instead of just "rand."

You can see the relevant source here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb#L16